# Creating a custom search engine for my whole Intranet site

Tags: full-text-search

To add a Whole Site Search feature to my Website, we have either to use Search Engines APIs (Which require Internet Access) as Google, or to install local Search Engines such as htdig, which are two advanced and efficient solutions, What if I don't need all the advanced services those solutions give me, Does anyone here know any other options (Methodologies or tools) which are more simple and native, Searching only some specific text contents is enough for me as a goal.

Comment: I think you're off-topic (mainly because you want to discuss general concepts and not concrete problems) and you should ask this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, Should I then move my question from here to that forum, or just copy it?

Comment: @konqi - this is much too broad for Programmers.  It will be quickly closed and likely down voted.  The question is trying to generate a discussion, and discussions don't fit within the SE Q&A format.

Comment: @GlenH7 indeed, but it could be fixed with a bit of editing and being more specific. Topicwise programmers is a better fit nonetheless. Whether it will be closed because it's too broad is a different question, although a good one.

Comment: @konqi - yes, the topicality is a better fit for Programmers, but the scope is much too broad.  If you can tighten the scope of this question with a bit of [edit]ing, then please do so.  Please consider having a read of this Meta.Progs post as well: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @YazidErman [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107), discussion does not work here. This network of sites is all about answers to practical questions.

Comment: Well, You are all right and I have copied this question to the link: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302385/creating-a-custom-search-engine-for-my-whole-intranet-site
I am editing now this post to be more specific.
Thank you.